# Sub select Contact->Account->Opportunities

Tags: soql

I'm selecting a Contact and in the same query I'd like to select the Contact's Account and that Account's Opportinities.

Here's what I think is the most reasonable of the queries I've tried:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    Email,
    AccountId,
    Account.Name,
    (SELECT
        AccountId,
        ContactId,
        Id,
        Name,
        StageName
    FROM
        Account.Opportunities
    )
FROM
    Contact
WHERE
    Name LIKE 'Hermes%'
```

I've also tried adjusting the `FROM` to `FROM Contact.Account.Opportunities`, which I wouldn't expect to work, but tried anyway.

Of course `FROM Opportunities` is not what I'm after as that would select the Opportunities for the Contact, not for the Account.

Is it possible to go this deep with sub-selects?

The error I get is:

```
InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE'
 exceptionMessage='
        Account.Opportunities
        ^
ERROR at Row:14:Column:9
First SObject of a nested query must be a child of its outer query.'
 extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
]
 row='14'
 column='9'
]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

From the base SObject (the one in the outermost `FROM`) we can query up to five levels up and one level down. If your query was based around Account, you could have one subquery to go down to the Contacts, and another subquery to go down to the Opportunities. Going up to Account and then down to Opportunity like you're trying to do isn't supported.

You can also use a semi-join (a subquery in the `WHERE` clause) to limit the results that are returned, similar to how it would behave if we could do this with a query based on Contact.

```sql
SELECT 
    Id, Name, 
    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts), 
    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities) 
FROM Account 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE 'Avi%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Opportunity object is child to the contact object and you need to use the `Opportunities` instead of `Account.Opportunities`.

Try with below query.

```
SELECT id, Email,name,AccountId,Account.Name,(select id, name,AccountId,contactid,StageName FROM opportunities) FROM contact WHERE Name LIKE 'Hermes%'
```

Comment: I did mention "FROM Opportunities is not what I'm after as that would select the Opportunities for the Contact, not for the Account."